# How do I store the real name of my application in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new to Powershell and I want to write a script to remove a windows 8 application. The name of my file changes everytime but usually has 'wardobs' in it. So I use this line of code to find the application.`get-appxpackage –Name *wardobs*` I then copy the package family name, paste it into this line of code `Remove-AppxPackage package family name` and it removes my app. Rather than me having to paste the package family name into my code, how can I find the app that contains 'wardobs' in its name. Store the package family name in a variable and use that variable in my final line of code to remove the app?

Answer (score 0):

```powershell
# Get all packages, where name of the package matches *wardobs*
$Appx = Get-AppxPackage –Name *wardobs*

# Your code here

# Remove all packages stored in the $Appx variable
$Appx | Remove-AppxPackage
```